# T-Distribution using Excel?

Tags: self-study, excel, t-distribution

I was given this sample problem:

> Find the t-value such that the area under the t distribution to the
>   right of the t-value is 0.2 assuming 10 degrees of freedom.

So, I went poking around in Excel and found a function called **TDIST**.  I plugged in my values:

- x = 0.2
- Degrees of Freedom = 10
- Tails = 1 (since I'm only concerned about the right tail)

The formula spits out 0.4922.  However, the sample answer is 0.879, which can be confirmed by googling a t-distribution table and seeing where 0.2 and 10 intersect.

Why the discrepancy, and is it possible to get the value that's in the t-distribution table by using any of Excel's functions?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about Statistics but about Excel

Comment: Well, it's sort of about doing Statistics **in** Excel.  But feel free to mark it for deletion if you don't think it's useful for anyone else.

Comment: I suppose it might be useful if you were to include your data...

Comment: It's hard to know exactly where to draw the line, but questions that are solely about how to do something with a particular software package or in a particular language are generally considered off-topic. In this case it's clear IMO: there must be dozens of software packages or languages with quantile functions for the t-distribution & CV isn't the place to precis all their manuals.

Comment: Although this question is about Excel, it addresses an issue that arises in most statistical software: how to distinguish two-sided quantiles from one-sided quantiles and how to convert one to the other. As such I am grateful it has appeared on this site and appreciate the answer that was posted.

Answer (score 3):

I figured this out, in case anyone ever needs it.

> =TINV(x*2, df)

So, in my example:

> =TINV(0.2*2, 10)

The answer is 0.879058.

Comment: The Excel function TDIST takes in a t ratio (and df and #tails) and reports a probability. TINV takes in a two-tailed probability (and df) and reports a t ratio.

From the Excel help:

TINV returns that value t, such that P(|X| > t) = probability where X is a random variable that follows the t-distribution and P(|X| > t) = P(X < -t or X > t).

A one-tailed t-value can be returned by replacing probability with 2*probability.